# REST API and Multi value date field

Tags: 7, services

I have a React native front end with D7 backend. I am populating a content type that has a multi-value Date field. I am successfully creating the content-type with all other fields except the Date field. The format I am sending via POST looks like :

```
"field__delivery_dates": {
        "und": [
           {
                "value": "2020-07-23"
               
            },
            {
                "value": "2020-08-05"
                
            },
            {
                "value": "2020-08-07"
                
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem is when I sent the multiple date field values it's getting submitting but the values are not reflected in drupal.

Anyone, please help me to find out a solution for sending a multi-field date field to drupal 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2014-08-21/services-and-date-field#comment-13101529

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can able to post date to my date field when it is a normal date field, But when I change the date field into multi-value date field drupal is not taking the date value, while sending the date values through REST service